# How do I stop emacs open certain files in conf-mode?

Tags: php-mode

By default, my Emacs opens `config.php` in `conf-mode`. It looks like `conf-mode` uses a set of regular expressions to match the filename, but I can't figure out how to make it open in `php-mode`.

Any idea?

Comment: That's because the entries for `conf-mode` come before the entries for `php-mode` in `auto-mode-alist`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an entry specifically for `config.php` into `auto-mode-alist`, as follows:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons (rx bos "config.php" eos) 'php-mode))
```

(Where `bos` and `eos` are shortcuts for `string-start` and `string-end`, abbreviated from Beginning/End Of String.)